# Using Hardware-Acceleration with VNC-Server for OBS Encoding

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, vnc, hardware-acceleration, obs-studio

i have the following setup:

- Intel Core i5-13500
- 64 GB RAM
- No GPU

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and connect via VNC which is set up acording to this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04

Everything runs fine, but when i try to set up programms that can use the hardware acceleration for video encoding (quicksync or qsv) from intel, i can't make use of it.

I installed `intel-media-va-driver-non-free libmfx1` but OBS for example does not give me the option to select it as an encoder. (I tried both, the current stable & newest beta)

I enabled the acceleration in /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
        Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection
```

If i use `glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"` to check if it's enabled, i get

> "Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig"

Am i missing something?